# Start Storyboard from Code Behind

Tags: wpf, vb.net, storyboard

I have a project with WPF 4/VB.net 2010. How do I begin a WPF storyboard named "ripple" from the vb.net code behind? It is in window resources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It ought to be:

```
Dim rippleStoryboard As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("ripple"), Storyboard)
rippleStoryboard.Begin()
```